# Failed to determine a suitable driver class- Springboot 2.7.9

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-rest, spring-boot-maven-plugin, spring-boot-admin

Description:
Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Comment: There is far too little information. You only posted a message (which already tells you what is wrong you didn't provide the `spring.datasource.url` property in your application properties). If you did include it there is far too little informaation in your question to even begin answering this question. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and improve your question with that knowledge.

Comment: please give more detail, for example what is you jdbc driver. It is better to leave the application.properties file here

Comment: spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ss
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
server.port=81 and am using Mysql 8 and java 8  springboot 2.7.9

Comment: Don't add additional information in comments, as that is totally undereadable. Instead edit your question.

Answer (score -1):

I think you MySQL port must change to 3306, but if you are sure about port number, change your application property like that:

```
 spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:81/ss 
spring.datasource.username=root spring.datasource.password=root 
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver 
spring.jpa.database-platform = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect 
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true 
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration 
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
```

Also  you must check is the other dependency for other databases exists in your POM.xml or not

Comment: Not Working , it's showing same issue

Comment: Am using mysql driver ,spring data jdbc, spring data jpa dependency in my project.

Comment: is ss databse exists on you mysql server?

Comment: yes ss datbase is exists on mysql localhost

Comment: pleas attention to autoconfigure.exclude

Comment: how can i implement autoconfigure in my code.

Comment: 6th line of my application.properties

Comment: yes, its working but not connected with database , also not created any table in database

Comment: The error states the `url` isn't configured. If the URL was wrong you will get a different exception (that it cannot connect to the database not that the `url` isn't specified).

Comment: Hi @M.Deinum my last project on springboot 2.6.7 is working good with mysql 8 but in springboot 2.7.9 it showing error , I tried all but not working  Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class